# How do I add new Grid Columns and Rows at runtime in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, maui

Over time, I have successfully added new child columns and rows to a Grid in a Xamarin.Forms app. I attempt to do the same thing in developing a .NET MAUI app and receive an error with the following line of code:

```cs
gridLayout.Children.Add(label, columnIndex, rowIndex);
```

> error CS1501  No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments

The syntax of the method has changed from accepting 3 arguments to only 1. Is this an error in the new .NET MAUI App development or is there another way to successfully add rows and columns at runtime?

I reported the problem to Microsoft. They have indicated there is an issue reported on GitHub already. It has been a few months since I have reported this and I have not heard from anyone with regards to an answer. Does anyone here experience the same issue? If so, what has been your solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to add new items dynamically to a `Grid` in .NET MAUI.

Your approach isn't wrong, you just need to use the `Add()` method directly on the `Grid`:

```cs
gridLayout.Add(label, columnIndex, rowIndex);
```

This uses the [Add(Grid, IView, Int32, Int32) extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.gridextensions.add#microsoft-maui-controls-gridextensions-add(microsoft-maui-controls-grid-microsoft-maui-iview-system-int32-system-int32)) for the `Grid` class.

You can find more examples in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid).

Comment: Simple fix and very much appreciated. Thank you so much @ewerspej